# Integrating over a interesting Manifold.

Tags: integration, general-topology, manifolds

I am writing a small paper on stokes generalised theorem namely: $\int_M d \omega=\int_{\partial M} \omega$.  And I want an example problem. And not just a calculus 3 problem.  Maybe over a Klien Bottle or something? I don't want a solution, just a problem.

Comment: You can't use Stokes' theorem on a Klein bottle because it is not orientable !

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Ah, yes I was wondering why I couldn't find anything!!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was found [here](https://secure.math.ucla.edu/gradquals/data/gt-16S.pdf).  On $\mathbb{R}^4$, with coordinates $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$, consider the form
\begin{equation}
\alpha=x_1 dx_2\wedge dx_3\wedge dx_4 - x_2dx_1\wedge dx_3\wedge dx_4 + x_3 dx_1\wedge dx_2\wedge dx_4 - x_4 dx_1\wedge dx_2\wedge dx_3.
\end{equation}
Let $\iota\colon S^3\hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^4$ be the inclusion map of the unit sphere into $\mathbb{R}^4$ and comptue $\int_{S^3}\iota^*\alpha$.

Notice that Stokes' tells us that $\int_{S^3}\iota^*\alpha=\int_{B^4}d\alpha$, where $B^4$ is the closed unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^4$.  When you compute $d\alpha$, you'll see that $\int_{B^4}d\alpha$ is a much easier integral to evaluate than the original.

Comment: Thank you, I like this problem.

Comment: Is $\alpha$ the volume form on the 3-sphere? If so, that might help explain why we'd be interested in integrating that form at all.

Comment: @GunnarÞórMagnússon No, the main reason we're interested in $\alpha$ is that $d\alpha$ is so much simpler than $\alpha$, and this makes it a good candidate for Stokes' theorem.

Comment: Where was this qualifying exam from?

Comment: It's from UCLA.

Comment: Would $d\alpha$ be $4dx_1\wedge dx_2\wedge dx_3\wedge dx_4$? Integrating this gives $\frac{4\pi^2}{\Gamma(3)} $to my calculations

Comment: @FelicioGrande Yes.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an interesting result proved with Stokes' theorem:

**A compact orientable smooth manifold M without boundary is not contractible.**

**Examples:**
a) No sphere $S^n (n\geq1)$ is contractible.
b)  No compact holomorphic manifold is contractible. In particular $\mathbb P^n(\mathbb C)\; (n\geq 1) $is not contractible.

**Proof of result:**
Let $n$ be the dimension of $M$ and let $\omega\in \Omega^n(M)$ be a smooth form with positive integral: $$\int_M\omega\gt0 \quad (\bigstar)$$ 
The existence of such an $\omega$ is easy to see: take an oriented chart $M\supset U\stackrel {\phi}{\to}\widetilde U\subset \mathbb R^n$, choose a non-negative  function $u\in C_c^\infty(\widetilde U)$ with compact (but non-empty !) support and just take $\omega =\phi^*(udx_1\cdots dx_n)$ (extended by zero on $M\setminus U$).
Then $\omega$ is closed (like all $n$-forms on $M$!) but not exact: indeed if we had $\omega=d\eta$, we would deduce by Stokes $$\int_M\omega =\int_M d\eta=\int_{\partial M}\eta=  \int_\emptyset\eta =0      $$  which contradicts $(\bigstar)$.
Since $\omega $ is closed but not exact its class $[\omega] \in H^n_{DR}(M)$ in the $n$-th De Rham cohomology group is not zero, so that $H^n_{DR}(M)\neq 0$ and thus $M$ is not contractible (because a contractible manifold has all $H^i_{DR}(M)=0$ for $i\gt0$).